# How to call objective-c singleton from swift

Tags: ios

I am porting an objective-c project to swift. I am attempting to call a singleton that shows a pickerView. The singleton is written in objective-c and works fine in my objective-c app.

Here's part of the .h file:

```
+(void)showPickerViewInView: (UIView *)view
                withStrings: (NSArray *)strings
                withOptions: (NSDictionary *)options
                 completion: (void(^)(NSString *selectedString))completion;

+(void)showPickerViewInView: (UIView *)view
                withObjects: (NSArray *)objects
                withOptions: (NSDictionary *)options
    objectToStringConverter: (NSString *(^)(id object))converter
       completion: (void(^)(id selectedObject))completion;

+(void)dismissWithCompletion: (void(^)(NSString *))completion;
```

Here's an example from the documentation of how to call it in obj-c:

```
[MMPickerView showPickerViewInView:self.view
                         withStrings:strings
                         withOptions:nil
                          completion:^(NSString *selectedString) {
                          //selectedString is the return value which you can use as you wish
    self.label.text = selectedString;
}];
```

The conversion from obj-c to swift syntax is giving me fits.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to *convert* the singleton from objective-c to swift or are you trying to *call it* from swift?

Comment: What errors are you getting? And show us the Swift code that is causing errors.

Comment: I'm trying to call it from swift. I've got the bridging header in place so once I get the syntax figured out I should be ready to go.